# How to cast GORM query to string

Tags: postgresql, go, orm, go-gorm

I am writing a web app in go and using the GORM for my ORM. I need to be able to retrieve all the metrics of a certain user and return it via JSON to be displayed on the front end. The query seems to run successfully but I only see a memory address when printing the results and receive an error when trying to cast the results the standard way.
Here is my current code

```
func DisplayData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //Get the data from the database
    var metric models.Metric
    results := db.Where("user_id = ?", "1").Find(&metric)


    //Write a json response
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    resp := make(map[string]string)
    resp["message"] = results
    jsonResp, err := json.Marshal(resp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error happened in JSON marshal. Err: %s", err)
    }
    w.Write(jsonResp)
    return
}
```

This results in the error

```
controllers/statsCont.go:116:18: cannot use results (type *gorm.DB) as type string in assignment
note: module requires Go 1.17
```

When I try to cast by surrounding result in string() it gives the following error.

```
controllers/statsCont.go:116:26: cannot convert results (type *gorm.DB) to type string
note: module requires Go 1.17
```

Comment: The query result is written to `metric`, not the db object returned from `Find`.  Initialize `resp` with `resp := map[string]interface{}{"message": metric }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @BaytaDarell the query result is added in the variable passed inside [`Find`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB.Find) method

The return value of [`Find`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB.Find) is different in the context it is called in case when it is called with db type the return type is [`(tx *DB)`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB.Find) and when called with associations type the return type is [`Error`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#Association.Find)

To solve the issue remove below lines

```golang
resp := make(map[string]string)
resp["message"] = results
```

And update it has

```golang
resp := map[string]interface{}{"message": metric}
```